# How to integrate Microsoft cognitive speech service in android studio?

Tags: android, speech

I want to use Microsoft cognitive speech API in my application. Can anyone describe the steps to use the API in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:
[New Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/cognitive-speech-stt-android/)